# How do I update my task list with basic javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am making a simple task list where I can add/ delete items at will but I'm not sure how to make the output reflect those changes when I try and delete an item? Or did I not set up my delete function correctly to delete items from the array? I was using the splice method to do this.

```js
(function(){
    
    // Variable that stores the tasks:
    var tasks = [];
    // Function called when the form is submitted.
    // Function adds a task to the global array.
    function addTask() {
        'use strict';
        var task = document.getElementById('task');
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        if (task.value) {
            tasks.push(task.value);
            displayList();
        } // End of task.value IF.

        // Return false to prevent submission:
        return false;
    } // End of addTask() function.
    
    function deleteTask(){
        'use strict';
        var deleteElement = prompt('Which task would you like to delete?', 'Enter task number');
        
        //check validity of input
        if( (isNumber(deleteElement)) ){
            
            for (var counter = 0, length = tasks.length; counter < length; counter++){
                if (deleteElement == tasks[counter]){
                    tasks.splice(tasks[counter] - 1, 1);
                }
            }
            displayList();
        }
        else{
            alert('Input must be a number');
        }
    }
    
    function displayList(){
        var message = '';
        message = '<h2>To-Do</h2><ol>';
        for (var i = 0, count = tasks.length; i < count; i++) {
            message += '<li>' + tasks[i] + '</li>';
        }
        message += '</ol>';
        output.innerHTML = message;
    }
    
    function isNumber(number){
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(number)) && isFinite(number);
    }

    // Initial setup:
    function init() {
        'use strict';
        document.getElementById('add_task').onclick = addTask;
        document.getElementById('delete').onclick = deleteTask;
    } // End of init() function.
    window.onload = init;
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/todo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Script 6.5 - task.html -->
    <!-- <form action="#" method="post" id="theForm">-->
    <div id="form">
        <fieldset><legend>Enter an Item To Be Done</legend>
            <div><label for="task">Task</label><input type="text" name="task" id="task" required></div>
            <input type="button" value="Add a task" id="add_task">
            <input type="button" value="Delete task" id="delete">
            <div id="output"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <!--</form>-->
    <script src="js/todo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to delete you do not need loop.

```
tasks.splice(+deleteElement-1,1)
```

would do. `-1` is required as your tasks start from `1` and array start from `0`

Also as an additional check, try

```
if ((isNumber(deleteElement)) && +deleteElement <= tasks.length) {
```

Error should come if value is not a number or its a number and exceeds limits. Also you will have to update the message accordingly.

Also a minor typo:

```
<div id="form"
```

should be

```
<div id="form">
//            ^
```

```js
(function() {

  // Variable that stores the tasks:
  var tasks = [];

  // Function called when the form is submitted.
  // Function adds a task to the global array.
  function addTask() {
    'use strict';
    var task = document.getElementById('task');
    var output = document.getElementById('output');


    if (task.value) {
      tasks.push(task.value);
      displayList();

    } // End of task.value IF.

    // Return false to prevent submission:
    return false;

  } // End of addTask() function.

  function deleteTask() {
    'use strict';
    var deleteElement = prompt('Which task would you like to delete?', 'Enter task number');

    //check validity of input
    if ((isNumber(deleteElement)) && +deleteElement <= tasks.length) {
   tasks.splice(+deleteElement-1,1)
      displayList();
    } else {
      alert('Input must be a valid task number');
    }
  }

  function displayList() {
    var message = '';
    message = '<h2>To-Do</h2><ol>';
    for (var i = 0, count = tasks.length; i < count; i++) {
      message += '<li>' + tasks[i] + '</li>';
    }
    message += '</ol>';
    output.innerHTML = message;

  }

  function isNumber(number) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(number)) && isFinite(number);
  }

  // Initial setup:
  function init() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('add_task').onclick = addTask;
    document.getElementById('delete').onclick = deleteTask;
  } // End of init() function.
  window.onload = init;

})();
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter an Item To Be Done</legend>
    <div>
      <label for="task">Task</label>
      <input type="text" name="task" id="task" required>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Add a task" id="add_task">
    <input type="button" value="Delete task" id="delete">
    <div id="output"></div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: dumb question but why do you need the plus sign in "+deleteElement"?

Comment: @MenjiXo it's just a shorthand for converting to number.